# RxAlamofire extension to hanlde error at one place

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, rx-swift, rxalamofire

Following is my code to do RxAlamofire requests

```
 RxAlamofire.request(request as URLRequestConvertible).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON().asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] (response) in
                if let json = response.data {
                    let jsonResult = JSON(json)
                    let foodMenuResult = MenuResult(jsonResult)
                    self?.delegate?.showMenu(menuResult: foodMenuResult)

                }

            }, onError: {  [weak self] (error) in
               // print(error.localizedDescription)
                 UIViewController().logAPIError(error: error)
                self?.delegate?.onError(MenuViewController.REQUEST_MENU)
            },onCompleted: {})
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I want to write extension related to Observable so that I can handle error at one place instead of writing same code on every  onError

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Do you want to _do_ the same thing for every error in your entire project?

Comment: Yes want to right some common for error for entire project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the most obvious solution:

```
func myRequest(_ request: URLRequestConvertable) -> Observable<T> {
    return RxAlamofire.request(request as URLRequestConvertible)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON()
        .asObservable()
        .do(onError: { /* do the thing you want to always do */ })
}
```

I don't use alamofire, but replace `T` in the above with whatever type the code emits.

Comment: There's no reason to. Just make it a free function and use it.

Comment: And where I can keep this function?

Comment: Anywhere. Put it in its own file if you want.